# Speech Comparison with Java

Tags: java, compare, speech-recognition

I am developing a system which includes a speech comparison. This system will be used by people having a speech disorder. Practically I need to capture the user's speech and compare it with a another speech audio file and return a percentage match. I need to develop this in Java.

I started doing some research and found that this can be done using some sort of algorithm using FFT.

Is there any other algorithms which you may suggest in order to implement this comparison of capturing the user voice and comparing it with a pre recorded audio file and perform a real time audio processing.

I need some assistance from you guys in which is the best way to handle this and develop it with the best practice.

Many thanks for your time! Much appreciated

Comment: Seems way too broad for stack overflow. Are you asking us to write your program for you?

Comment: @Robert Thank you very much for your reply, I am not asking you to write the program for me as that is not the purpose of stackoverflow. I wish I could provide some code which you can view, amend and discuss further, however I am still in the early stage of this project and therefore I Posted a discussion question which still abides with the rules of this forum. But many thanks for your time in reading my question anyways !

Comment: The first part of the [StackOverflow Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) states "*Ask questions, get answers, no distractions*", so discussion questions don't fit in on this site (and if the answer to the question has high enough demand to be asked, should be asked as a community wiki) . **Although**, [On-Topic Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) states that questions about algorithms are alright. I'd say this question just needs a little reformatting. Ask about the algorithm that's confusing you, not the entire subject that requires it

Comment: @VinceEmigh many thanks for your comment! I will reword my question in a further way to discuss more the algorithm required to make this system in practice !

Answer (score 2):

This answer may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3487136/2930268

Basically, [this](http://blog.datasingularity.com/?p=53) blog post shows an implementation of the FFT algorithm using Java.

Comment: There is also some more information in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9239032/2930268

Comment: Many thanks you the above information, I have already taken a look at the above and they are very help full, however I still ned some guidance in what solution to involve myself more research in when coming to compare two audio files including only text. What element should be analysed and compared against what ? I would appreciate if your profession involves this knowledge

Comment: Given that you've just pointed to another answer on SO (and added a slight color commentary in the form of a link that's also present in the answer to that question), maybe this answer should instead be a vote to close-as-duplicate?